# How to write an 'always-on-top' view like Youtube's Video Player? (PIP for Android)

Tags: java, android, youtube, window, overlay

I wonder how Google wrote its Media Player so that it could be always on top of any activity we open.

An easy guess would be, it is attaching the view to the Window. But, the way how it works with swipe and tap makes me think, if it is possible to do so with view attached to a window at all.

I Could not find any blogs or questions around. Thats why I am asking for some tips here. Thanks in advance.

[image: PIP of Youtube] [image]

Comment: But, when you open a new activity from the activity where the player is attached, the player will be hidden.

Comment: make everything in one activity.

Comment: see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top

Comment: have you found a way to do this? I'm facing the same problem